# Foreach nao pega $value

Tags: php, libcurl

meu `foreach` esta retornando somente a `$key` e o `$value` exibe apenas `Array`.
O que pode estar errado com meu código?

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.instagram.com/p/CLm2laRsp8I/?__a=1');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$data = json_decode($query, true);
curl_close($curl_handle);

foreach ($data["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["edge_media_to_parent_comment"]["edges"] as $array) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
print "$key : $value<br>";
}
}
```

Retorno:

```
Warning: Array to string conversion
node : Array
Warning: Array to string conversion
node : Array
```

Comment: Como você mesmo disse, seu value é um array, você não pode fazer um print como se fosse uma string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você está usando `print` para exibir um *array*, deveria usar `print_r($value,true)`. Esta função retornará o `value` e transformará em *string*.

```
print "$key : ". print_r($value,true) . "<br>"
```

Comment: print "$key : ". print_r($value,true) .  "<br>"

Comment: Você pode editar a resposta para incluir as informações no comentário. Existe alguns erros de digitação em sua resposta, poderia aproveitar para fazer essas correções.

Comment: Obrigado! Problema resolvido.